# EXCEL: Count a cell if cells relative to it have certain values

Tags: excel

What I want to do is count the cells with any number value (`=count`) in the last column (F) IF the cells in the same row have certain values.  For example, let's say I want the first column (A) to contain "Bleach", the second to contain ".05", and the third to contain "2".  I only want to count the cells in column F if those cells in the same row have those values.
I have no clue how to do this, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If layout allows you, create a new column that has a formula like if (and(a = 'bleache',b=0.5,c=2),1,0) and make the count on this column and hide it afterwards.

Also I saw a new formula (never used it personally) you should check it:
 http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/countifs-function-HA102753238.aspx?CTT=1

Answer (score 0):

Excel does have a [`COUNTIF`](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx) function that does exactly what you're looking for.

You specify a range and a criteria.  If the criteria is true, then the value is counted.

Comment: I've actually tried to use `COUNTIF` and `COUNTIFS`, but I haven't been able to get it to do what I want.  Help?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=SUMIFS(F:F,A:A,"Bleach",B:B,0.05,C:C,2)
```

Comment: Close, but I want to count the number of cells with a number value in it, as I'm using a binary (1's and 0's) system.  This returns 46 when it should return 48.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, but it did help me come up with something that will do for now.  Thanks!